# Java - Scanner/symbol errors

Tags: java, symbols

I'm pretty new to this, working on a beginner's Java course.  Tasked to search a string for information, but getting the errors below.

First up, the code.

```
/***********************************************************************
* Identify if webpage is secure or unencrypted given full HTML path    *
***********************************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringy {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Paste the web address into the prompt: ");   //collect web address from user
    String webPath = scan.next();

    CharSequence seq = "https://";                     //search for https:
    boolean testCase = test.contains(seq);
    System.out.println("Found https://" + testCase);

    boolean testPositive = test.contains("https://");     //if found https, notify user
    System.out.println("This website is secure.  Continue exercising caution while browsing.");

    CharSequence seq2 = "http://";                     //search for https:
    boolean testCase2 = test.contains(seq2);
    System.out.println("Found https://" + testCase2);

    boolean testNegative = test.contains("http://");     //if found http, notify user
    System.out.println("This website is unencrypted!" + '\n');
    System.out.println("Do not post personal or sensitive information in any form or field on this page." + '\n');
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
C:\Users\name\Documents\School\Intro to Programming (JAVA)\Week 3\stringy.java:15: error: cannot find symbol  
    String webPath = scan.next();  
                     ^  
  symbol:   variable scan  
  location: class stringy  
C:\Users\name\Documents\School\Intro to Programming (JAVA)\Week 3\stringy.java:18: error: cannot find symbol  
    boolean testCase = test.contains(seq);  
                       ^  
  symbol:   variable test  
  location: class stringy  
C:\Users\name\Documents\School\Intro to Programming (JAVA)\Week 3\stringy.java:21: error: cannot find symbol  
    boolean testPositive = test.contains("https://");     //if found https, notify user  
                           ^  
  symbol:   variable test  
  location: class stringy  
C:\Users\name\Documents\School\Intro to Programming (JAVA)\Week 3\stringy.java:25: error: cannot find symbol  
    boolean testCase2 = test.contains(seq2);  
                        ^  
  symbol:   variable test  
  location: class stringy  
C:\Users\name\Documents\School\Intro to Programming (JAVA)\Week 3\stringy.java:28: error: cannot find symbol  
    boolean testNegative = test.contains("http://");     //if found http, notify user  
                           ^  
  symbol:   variable test  
  location: class stringy  
5 errors  

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: use `userInput` instead of `scan`. ex: `String webPath = userInput.next();`

Comment: Your scanner is named `userInput` not `scan`.... Where is test variable set?

Comment: Keep in mind, most developers use an IDE, which often highlights these errors before you attempt to run the code

Comment: @cricket_007 - I'll check that.  That may be the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two porblems in your code :

**First**:

> You have assigned scanner to using this line :
>   `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);`
>
> So,you should use `userInput` instead of scan in this line:`String webPath = scan.next();` **like** `String userInput = scan.next();`

**Second**

> You have not set test variable before using it so,assign the test variable before using.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Ended up skipping boolean as well and using just "webPath.contains("https://");" in an "IF" statement